# interaction between webplatform and unity3d project?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, laravel-5, gear-vr

I built a website using Laravel 5 and a dynamic unity project for virtual tour, but I need some ideas to know how I can communicate between these two. The web platform must send the data to the unity project, the unity project must compile and build it to give me the package I would like to get iOS, Android, GearVR..., and send the download link to the web platform.
I need help or idea that could resolve this issue.

Comment: are you trying to choose what asset to download depending on the platform or what app to point the user to depending on the platform?

Comment: from my web platform the user uploads his 360° images where the unity project can download them and use them as textures .So what i want is how i can communicate between the two of them where i host my unity project and i could acces to it from my my web platform

Comment: If you want users to upload videos then you can't bake them into the Unity app. You'll have to store them and then create an API that the Unity app will use the figure out what videos are available. Then download them via WWW class, retrieve the video and then use it as a texture. You'll need a plugin that's gonna do the decoding and transform each frame into a texture.

Comment: the unity part is done i can get the files , read them and download them into my unity project to be flexible when i use them as texture but the problem i got is how communicate between them . where i host my dynamic unity project and have the possibility to build it (how) and get download link for the package into my website